# How to get correct Bit wise left shift value for negative numbers?

Tags: javascript, binary, bitwise-operators

I want to get the binary value for negative number in Bitwise Left Shift for -12. Following code works fine,

```
console.log(parseInt(`${(-12 >>> 0).toString(2).slice(5 * -1)}000`, 2).toString(2));
```

which returns `10100000`

However, I think correct code would be

```
console.log((-12 << 3).toString(2))
```

but this one returns `-1100000` which is not correct result for my scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you shift a negative number, it stays negative.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(((-12 << 3) >>> 0).toString(2))` ?

Comment: If you want precise control of how the bits are interpreted for bitwise operations (and to avoid JavaScript's horrible performance with bitwise), WebAssembly gives you explicitly signed and unsigned variants.